# Selenium Server ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-server

I have Selenium Server 3.141.59 installed. I run it as a node via command

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.137.1:4444/grid/register/
```

Test code in Java creates WebDriver this way

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");  // Path to version 88
this.driver = new RemoteWebDriver("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub");
```

Test ends up with error: **SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80**

How can I force Selenium Server to use project local driver?

Current version of Chrome is 88.

Comment: "chromedriver.exe" is not a path. It's likely looking in your Windows PATH and finding the old version there. Ideally you would delete all other versions and either put v88 in your PATH or put the full path to v88 in your code.

Comment: chromedriver.exe should be relative path in the project root.

Comment: It does not matter if there is a full path or relative. `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\SeleniumTests\\VPS test\\chromedriver.exe");`

Comment: I had the wrong driver in the selenium server root.